# Pyspark split csv file in packets

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, split, pyspark

I'm very new in spark and I'm still with my first tests with it. I installed one single node and I'm using it as my master on a decent server running:

```
pyspark --master local[20]
```

And of course I'm facing some difficulties with my first steps using pyspark.

I have a CSV file of 40GB and around 300 million lines on it. What I want to do is to find the fastest way to split this file over and make small packages of it and store them as CSV files as well. For that I have two scenarios:

**First one.** Split the file without any criteria. Just split it equally into lets say 100 pieces (3 million rows each).

**Second one.** The CSV data I'm loading is a tabular one and I have one column **X** with 100K different IDs. What I woudl like to do is to create a set of dictionaries and create smaller pieces of CSV files where my dictionaries will tell me to which package each row should go.

So far, this is where I'm now:

```
sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate()

file_1 = r'D:\PATH\TOFILE\data.csv'

sdf = spark.read.option("header","true").csv(file_1, sep=";", encoding='cp1252')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (and probably "fastest") way to do this would be to take advantage of the in-built partitioning of RDDs by Spark and write to one CSV file from each partition. You may `repartition` or `coalesce` to create the desired number of partitions (let's say, 100) you want. This will give you maximum parallelism (based on your cluster resources and configurations) as each Spark Executor works on the task on one partition at a time.

You may do one of these:

1. Do a `mapPartition` over the Dataframe and write each `partition` to a unique CSV file.
2. OR `df.write.partitionBy("X").csv('mycsv.csv')`, which will create one partition (and thereby file) per unique entry in `"X"`

Note. If you use HDFS to store your CSV files, Spark will automatically create multiple files to store the different partitions (number of files created = number of RDD partitions).

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I read more about `partitions` and the operations `repartition` and `coalesce`. And at last I was able to split my original file in very homogeneous sized parititions containing a set of same values on each one of them...

Answer (score 0):

What I did at last was to load the data as a spark dataframe and spark automatically creates equal sized parititions of 128MB (default configuration of hive) and then I used the `repartition` method to redistribute my rows according the values for a specific column on my dataframe.

```
# This will load my CSV data on a spark dataframe and will generate the requiered amount of 128MB partitions to store my raw data.
sdf = spark.read.option('header','true').csv(file_1, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
# This line will redistribute the rows of each paritition according the values on a specific column. Here I'm placing all rows with the same set of values on the same partition and I'm creating 20 of them. (Sparks handle to allocate the rows so the partitions will be the same size)
sdf_2 = sdf.repartition(20, 'TARGET_COLUMN')
# This line will save all my 20 partitions on different csv files
sdf_2.write.saveAsTable('CSVBuckets', format='csv', sep=';', mode='overwrite', path=output_path, header='True')
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to split a csv file is to use unix utils called `split`.

Just google split unix command line.
I split my files using `split -l 3500 XBTUSDorderbooks4.csv orderbooks`